# QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

My HQL request

```
SELECT p FROM Payment p 
LEFT JOIN FETCH p.paymentProperties pr ON p.id = pr.payment.id 
WHERE 
p.user.id = :userId ORDER BY id DESC
```

Data class entity

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "t_payment")
public class Payment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn (name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "payment", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private List<PaymentProperty> paymentProperties;
}


@Entity
@Table (name = "t_payment_property")
public class PaymentProperty {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn (name = "payment_id", nullable = false)
    private Payment payment;

}


@Entity
@Table (name = "t_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

In result exception: QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters

Any ideas have to fix it, without removing fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to us this query should work:

```
  SELECT p FROM Payment p 
  LEFT JOIN FETCH p.paymentProperties pr  
   WHERE p.id = pr.payment.id
   AND   p.user.id = :userId 
   ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Comment: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous

Comment: id is ambiguous, Try now @Ant20

Comment: HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory! 

but work, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `ON p.id = pr.payment.id`. It's not SQL but HQL

```
SELECT p FROM Payment p 
LEFT JOIN FETCH p.paymentProperties pr
WHERE 
p.user.id = :userId ORDER BY p.id DESC
```